# How to run Rust tests with an explicit time zone using chrono?

Tags: testing, time, rust, automated-tests

I am building some tests that do timestamp conversions in Rust using the chrono crate. I need to make sure they take into account the local time zone but the tests will be run in multiple time zones and so will fail for most testers. How can I force Rust or chrono within the code to use a specific time zone when running tests?

I know about setting `env TZ=CST` or similar. Since I cannot control that part of the execution environment for all those running `cargo test`, I don't think this works for us.

Comment: Why not use [`std::env::set_var`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/env/fn.set_var.html) to set the variable at the start of each test? Or maybe even a lazy static?

Comment: I don't understand your problem

Comment: @OptimisticPeach I don't think that would work because the tests run in parallel by default (unless you force them not to) in which case they would override the same environment variable non-deterministically.

Comment: @OptimisticPeach that approach works so long as nothing else reads a local time before you set `TZ`. I had assumed (wrongly) that the creation of the `Local` time zone in chrono would cause that to be read before I could change it. I have actually tested now and it works, though it may be fragile if the order of operations change.

Answer (score 2):

If all tests should run in the **same** timezone, you can use [`std::sync::Once`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/struct.Once.html) to initialize the `TZ`-environment variable as pointed out in the comments. Technically, since there is no race condition, all tests could initialize the env to that timezone.

If tests need to set their own time-zone - valid only for that one test - it's probably safest to still modify the timezone for the entire process (including `chrono`, yet somewhere down in `libc` dragons may access the tz as well). As you pointed out yourself, multiple tests need to synchronize over their shared environment. You can do that with a `lazy_static`:

```
#[macro_use]
extern crate lazy_static;

lazy_static! {
    static ref TZ_LOCK: std::sync::Mutex<()> = std::sync::Mutex::new(());
}

fn with_tz<R, F: FnOnce() -> Result<(), R>>(tz: &str, f: F) -> Result<(), R> {
    let tz_lock = TZ_LOCK.lock();
    std::env::set_var("TZ", tz);
    f()
}

#[test]
fn foobar() -> Result<(), ()> {
    with_tz("CET", || {
        Ok(())
    })
}
```

You can get more fancy with this by using a more complex `TZ_LOCK` where all threads which currently want to run under the same timezone get to run simultaneously.

Comment: Indeed, chrono doesn't directly access the tz, it does it through the old time crate, which probably still relies on libc functions to do the dirty work a little more portably. AFAIK however, libc only loads the time zone once on first use, so it is not likely possible to change it within a single test.